# Model-View-Controller: When programming in Qt does the model automatically update the data?

Tags: model-view-controller, pyqt

This is just a theoretical question, I am new to PyQT. I am not able to identify classes or code examples that will show how the model updates the data (if that is done via Qt)

Right now my understanding is that the programmer is responsible for writing the methods/code for updating the data when a change is done in the model data.

Am I correct ?

**Update:** It seems that my question needs a drawing :-) 
So it is data as in data stored in a database. By my understanding the data in this picture is the data stored in the database not the data that the model is based on which is a subset of the data in the database

[image]

Comment: The answer to this question depends on whether you are using a custom model (aka a subclass of one of the Qt base models) or one of the standard ones that comes with Qt (like `QStandardItemModel`)

Comment: When I am trying to identify classes that means that I am looking for standard classes. If we speak about writing code for updating data it means that by default the standard classes don't do that.

Answer (score 1):

Try following some of the [tutorials](https://wiki.qt.io/PySide_Tutorials) and look at the example programs provided with PyQt or PySide.

A model is an object which stores data. This can be as simple as a list of strings. A view is an object which displays data. Qt provides some standard models for storing common types of data and some standard views for displaying common types of data. For simple cases you can use these pre-built components. These components have standard methods for adding or removing data from the model, or updating the view as the model changes. These changes are propagated from the model to the view, or from the view or control widgets to the model, using signals. Thanks to standardized naming of methods and signals this all works pretty seamlessly.

However your specific data storage or data presentation needs might be a bit different. In this case you can implement a custom model or a custom view, or if necessary both. You implement your custom model (or view) by subclassing one of the classes provided by the framework. You have to implement specific named methods on these subclasses because it's the standard naming that makes the automatic behavior with other components work, but can also add your own custom methods and such as you see fit.

Further to MiniMe's comment:

Lets look at an example. Qt Models have a xx.setData() method to update a data item, which takes parameters specifying where in the model the data goes (index) and the new data. When you implement that method, you perform the work of updating the data to whatever underlying storage mechanism you use (e.g. a list or dictionary) and emit the xx.dataChanged() signal. If any views are linked to this model, they will have subscribed to this signal and so will update themselves automatically.

```
def setData(self, index, value):
    # Update the data in the underlying python list self.my_list
    # The index object is of a data type provided by Qt. To perform
    # this operation we have to extract the row number where the change
    # is to be made, then use that to update the appropriate entry in
    # the list.
    self.my_list[index.row()] = value

    # Create a PyQt modelIndex object based on the row number that was
    # updated. The self.index() method is provided by Qt.
    modelIndex = self.index(index.row())

    # Send the modelIndex of the change to any connected views so they
    # know to update themselves
    self.dataChanged.emit(modelIndex)

    # In reality we'd do some validation checks and return False if there
    # was a problem and the data change didn't happen.
    return True
```

Similar methods would need to be implemented for adding a new data item in the list or removing a data item from the list. These methods would make the change, send a signal indicating which part of the model had changed to any attached views, then return. I hope this is more helpful.

Comment: Thanks Simon but your answer explain things that I knew. I need to understand if Qt has any means to update the data when the model data changes or I have to write my own model. What you are describing above is  how to create a model and a view which I do not need to understand

Comment: I have updated my question with a picture. I still believe that your answer is not addressing my question

Comment: Ok, I think I understand.  I assumed when you said 'update the data' you meant update it in the views as you didn't mention an external data store. Yes, you update the underlying database in your model code. In my example, this is the line that modifies the element in self.my_list. Instead you would write the update to the back-end database.

Comment: So the answer is "you write your own methods, Qt does not provide any" correct?

Comment: It does provide some, like self.dataChanged.emit() and self.index() but these are realy 'helper' functions. Plus it provides the classes for e.g. model indexes. So it provides the standardised components as well. But if you want a custom model with custom behavior you still have to write a bit of code. After all, Qt doesn't know anything about your external database so you need to write a Qt model that provides a Qt compliant interface to it. You do actually get a fair bit of functionality from that interface though.